# Cannot copy sequence with size 11 to array axis with dimension 0

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have written a function in python in order to do some experiments on dataframe 'Demand' using information in each row of dataframe 'File2':

```
   def Compute(row):

        File = pd.concat([File2[ (File2.Number == row['Number']) ]]*len(Demand), ignore_index = True)

        File.Number = Demand.Number

        result = pd.merge(Demand, File, on = 'Number')

        result['Situation'] = 0

        result.Situation = result.apply(lambda r: 1 if (r.Arrival <= r.Time2) & (r.Departure > r.Time2) & (r.Scenario == r.Scenario2) & (sum(pd.Series(r.Station).isin([row['Station2']])) != 0) else 0, axis = 1)

        if len(result) != 0:

            result = result[ (result.Situation == 1) ]

            return result


    File2.apply(Compute, axis = 1)
```

While I don't get any error using simple for loop on 'File2', I am getting the following error when I use this function:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-133-cbdaa2bf5936>", line 1, in <module>
      File2.apply(Compute, axis = 1)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3972, in apply
      return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4081, in _apply_standard
      result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 226, in __init__
      mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
dtype=dtype)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5163, in _arrays_to_mgr
      arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5477, in _homogenize
raise_cast_failure=False)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2887, in _sanitize_array
subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

      File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 2011, in _asarray_tuplesafe
      result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]

      ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 11 to array axis with dimension 0

      "cannot copy sequence with size 11 to array axis with dimension 0"
```

Could you please tell me what is the potential problem?

Comment: Could you include the full traceback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner. What is traceback?

Comment: All of the other stuff that comes with the error message

Comment: It displays the state of the call stack before the error. It's the long piece of text before the error itself with function and file names, line numbers and rows of code. It would make pinpointing where the error is actually generated a lot easier.

Comment: I added them to the question.

Comment: You are passing to `File2.apply()` the function name (Compute). However, I think that you should pass a call to that function, with your desired row e.g. `File2.apply(Compute('enter_your_row_here'), axis=1)`

Comment: But I want it to be ran on all 'File2' rows. Will File2.apply(Compute(row), axis = 1) work for me?